# Create CAGradient Layer with transparent hole in it?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

Currently I do it like this:

```
final class BorderedButton: BottomNavigationButton {

private let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let radius = bounds.size.height / 2
    let outside = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height), cornerRadius: radius)
    let inside = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 3.0, y: 3.0, width: bounds.width - 6, height: bounds.height - 6), cornerRadius: radius - 3)
    outside.append(inside)
    outside.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
    shapeLayer.path = outside.cgPath
}

init(color: UIColor?) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)

    let isGradient = color == nil

    shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.insertSublayer(shapeLayer, at: 0)
    //gradient part
    gradient.colors = isGradient ? [Constants.gradientStart, Constants.gradientEnd] : [color!.cgColor, color!.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
}
}
```

How can I apply that gradient to my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't add the `CAShapeLayer` to the view's `layer`, rather set it as the `mask` of the `CAGradientLayer`. Also don't forget to set the bounds of the gradient layer.

I had to make some modifications to get it to run in a playground, but this works for me:

```
let gradientStart = UIColor.orange
let gradientEnd = UIColor.blue

final class BorderedButton: UIButton {

    private let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    private let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let radius = bounds.size.height / 2
        let outside = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: bounds.width, height: bounds.height), cornerRadius: radius)
        let inside = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: 3.0, y: 3.0, width: bounds.width - 6, height: bounds.height - 6), cornerRadius: radius - 3)
        outside.append(inside)
        outside.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        shapeLayer.path = outside.cgPath
        gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bounds.size.width, height: bounds.size.height)
    }

    init(color: UIColor?, frame: CGRect = .zero) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let isGradient = color == nil

        shapeLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd

        //gradient part
        gradient.colors = isGradient ? [gradientStart.cgColor, gradientEnd.cgColor] : [color!.cgColor, color!.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.2, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)

        gradient.mask = shapeLayer

        layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```